# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

When I display the name of table using the id of another table in Laravel I declare like this. But when I want to get the id to edit, the error is like the title. Please help me, I am very grateful.

`Controller`
public function manage_departments(){

```
    $manage_departments=DB::table('departments')
    ->join('faculties','faculties.id','=','departments.faculty_id')
    ->orderBy('departments.created_at','desc')->get();

    $all_manage_departments=view('admin.manage-departments')->with('manage_departments', $manage_departments);

    return view('layouts.master')->with('admin.manage-departments', $all_manage_departments);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have `select` in your query builder. As [laravel doc](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#selects) said, you can specify what do you want to select in `select` method. I select `faculties.id` and `departments.id` for example.

```
DB::table('departments')
    ->select('faculties.id','departments.id')
    ->join('faculties','faculties.id','=','departments.faculty_id')
    ->orderBy('departments.created_at','desc')->get();
```